# Android client socket cannot write after flush

Tags: java, android, sockets

I can not send data after `flush()` and without flush it doesn't work...

```
package exm.co.me;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socket extends Activity {
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in=null;

    BufferedWriter out;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_socket);
        new backTask().execute();
    }

    public void submit(View v){
        EditText m=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg);
        String s=m.getText().toString();
        send(s);
    }

    public void send(String m){

        try{
            out=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.write(m);
            out.write("\n done.....");
            out.flush();
            Log.d("TcpClient","sent: "+m);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public void setSocket() throws IOException{
        socket=new Socket("192.168.56.1",8080);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        send("connecting......");
        send("connecting 2......");
        new Thread(){
            @Override public void run(){
            int i;

            while(true){
                try{

                    String inMsg=in.readLine();
                    Log.i("TcpClient","received: "+inMsg);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }
            }
        }.start();
        send("connected....");

    }

    public class backTask extends AsyncTask{
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params){
            try{
                setSocket();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`out.wirte();` does not work after flush whay?

I am receiving in server:

```
connecting....
done...
```

but not geting:

```
connectiong 2.... connected...
```

I am using php for server side...

```
    <?php
$host = "192.168.56.1";
$port = 8080;
$message = "Hello Client";
set_time_limit(0);

function messege_recived($msg){
if($msg=="exit"){
global $socket,$com;
echo '
server closed';
}
}
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
echo 'listining ip '.$host." at port ".$port;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$com = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($com, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
$input = trim($input);
//message_recived($input);
echo '
Client says: '.$input;

//socket_write($com, $message , strlen ($message)) or die("Could not write output\n");
}
echo '
server closed';
socket_close($com);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: 'public class socket extends Activity'. Don't call your activity a socket. Because it is not.

Comment: Do not create a new buffered writer for every send(). Remove the use of a Thread for reading.

Comment: removed new buffer from send() to setSocket() still same problem..

Comment: You did not react on my suggestion to remove the thread. You did not adapt your code here.

Comment: public void send(String m){
try{
o.writeUTF(m);
}catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d("TcpClient","sent: "+m);


}
public void setSocket() throws IOException{
socket=new Socket("192.168.56.1",8080);
o=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
send("connecting...");send("connected...");
//out=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
//in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
//String inMsg=in.readLine();
}

Comment: I dont know how to past code here..

Comment: I think problem in server side code

Comment: I am using php for server side

Comment: 'dont know how to past code here..'. If you can add -php- code then you can edit your original code. Please do as in comments it's unreadable as you can see your self.

Comment: **bold** _this is italic_ `<?php echo 'this is code';?> @greenapps not working

Comment: how can I past code in commnet section?